# C++ - Is it possible to edit the data inside an ifstream?

Tags: c++, boost, ifstream, boost-gil

I'm trying to use Boost-GIL to load an image. The read_image function takes ifstream as a parameter, but I will already have the image as a base64 encoded string. Is it possible for me to add the decoded image into an ifstream manually, so that I wont have to write and read from disk to get the image loaded into GIL? Another possibility could be to somehow use a string stream to add the data and cast that to an ifstream, though I haven't had luck trying that.

Comment: Does the function take an `ifstream` or an `istream`?

Comment: Did you try the example in [Boost GIL - Reading And Writing In-Memory Buffers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/gil/doc/html/io.html)?

Comment: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/gil-io-new-review-Reading-images-from-in-memory-sources-td3073639.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Boost.GIL`'s `read_image` function you mentioned seems to support `istream` interface. If you have an array, you can make use of `boost.iostreams` to represent the array as a stream.

Here is a made-up example since you do not provide a code snippet.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/gil.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/io/read_image.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/tiff.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const char* data = "decoded-data";
  boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> in{data, std::strlen(data)};
  boost::gil::rgb8_image_t img;
  read_image(in, img, boost::gil::tiff_tag());

  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::stringstream` to store your decoded image and give that to the `read_image` function. Something along the lines of:

```
#include <boost/archive/iterators/binary_from_base64.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/insert_linebreaks.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/ostream_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/gil.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/io/read_image.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/tiff.hpp>

#include <sstream>

using base64_decode_iterator = transform_width<binary_from_base64<const char*>, 8, 6>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const char* data = "base64-data";
  std::stringstream ss;

  std::copy(
    base64_decode_iterator{data},
    base64_decode_iterator{data + std::strlen(data)},
    std::ostream_iterator<char>{ss}
  );
  boost::gil::rgb8_image_t img;
  read_image(ss, img, boost::gil::tiff_tag());

  return 0;
}
```